# An unexpected behavior of LastIndexOf()?

Tags: c#

While using LastIndexOf to search for a short string in a longer string I came across behavior that I find somewhat counterintuitive:

If I have a haystack and a needle:

```
var h = "abcabcabc";
var n = "abc";
```

And I tell LastIndexOf to start searching at index 3, 4, I would expect it to start looking there and proceed towards the start of the string, and hence return 3:

```
012345678
abcabcabc
    abc    <- try index 4, no
   abc     <- found at index 3
```

..but it actually locates the first `abc` and returns 0. It behaves like there is an assumption "user wants to start searching for a string of length 3 starting at index 4; the string couldn't possibly occur at any index higher than 2 so search will begin from index 2.. found at index 0" - while that would be true if one was starting from the very end of the string i.e. a needle of length 3 couldn't possibly be found any later than `haystack.Length-3`, I don't find it logical to adopt the approach in the middle of a string

Another way of looking at it is "the haystack is substringed so that it has a length equal to the startIndex and then the substringed haystack is searched" - but again, I don't find it reasonable to chop a document and remove a potential match

While I can reason the search logic out thus and try to remember it, it seems illogical to me to operate in such a manner, so I'm here asking if there is some underlying reason for this behavior that will make it easier to reason about?

Note: it's also fine to say "no, your logic of "start at 4, find at 3 is unreasonable because.." - it would help adjust my mental model of how I think LastIndexOf should work

Comment: Note; I appreciate I could read the source, but it's quite convoluted, especially when the culture stuff is added, and eventually drops into a windows api call/browsing it on a cellphone is a bit of a challenge

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `h.LastIndexOf(n, 5)` returns 3 for me.

Comment: Whereas using 3 or 4 as the start position *does* return 0.

Comment: The documentation does make it clear though, it's searching AS IF the string was as long as the value you pass for `starttIndex`. `The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string.`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Could you quote which bit of the documentation clarifies that? I'm looking now and I can't see it. (It's definitely surprising for me too.)

Comment: @JonSkeet The bit I quoted was from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-lastindexof(system-string-system-int32), specifically `The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string.`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: But that doesn't really clarify it for me. Reading that, I'd still expect it to mean "The search starts with the specified character position as being the greatest possible value to return, i.e. the latest starting point to consider, and work backwards from there."

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess it must be ambiguous, but I read it as meaning it searches backwards from the specified index, so it would never match any characters after that index.

Comment: There is a comment [in the source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Searching.cs,20e42ee05c19254a) which is a little more explicit: `For LastIndexOf specifially, overloads which take a 'startIndex' and 'count' behave differently than their IndexOf counterparts. 'startIndex' is the index of the last char element that should be considered when performing the search. For example, if startIndex = 4, then the caller is indicating "when finding the match I want you to include the char element at index 4, but not any char elements past that point.`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Wow, that's *so* much clearer than the docs. I think "starts at" on its own is super-unclear... if I were given the current docs as a specification, I'd basically have a loop of `for (int index = startIndex; index >=0; index--) { .... }`. That to me is what "the search starts at..." means.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the sanity check  on index 5 - fixed

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks; I'd read the docs and come to the same assumption as Jon; that the startIndex was merely where to start the search from but it *would* use characters after that in trying for a match - IndexOf *would* be able to find a match occurring rightwards within needle.Length chars of the start, but LastIndexOf doesn't find a match occurring leftwards within needle.Length-1 chars of the start.. All in the source code comment has cleared it up that conceptually the haystack is substring'd to a length of start+1, bizarre as I find it.I wondered if it might be a consequence of the ..

Comment: specifics of the underlying search algorithm (KMP etc rather than eg brute force?)

Answer (score 3):

from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-6.0#system-string-lastindexof(system-string-system-int32)) - it says

> Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a
> specified string within this instance. The search starts at a
> specified character position and proceeds backward toward the
> beginning of the string.

So it searches from the value **to** the beginning of the string. Different  starting point as your expectation.

**Update:** as Matthew Watson mentioned in his comment from the [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.Searching.cs,20e42ee05c19254a)

> For LastIndexOf specifially, overloads which take a 'startIndex' and 'count' behave differently than their IndexOf counterparts. 'startIndex' is the index of the last char element that should be considered when performing the search. For example, if startIndex = 4, then the caller is indicating "when finding the match I want you to include the char element at index 4, but not any char elements past that point.

```
var h = "abcabcabc";
//index  012345678
//          ^ last element that will be considdered "abca"
var n = "abc";
int result = h.LastIndexOf(n,3); //0
```

Comment: No, I don't think it's a different *direction*. It's a different *starting point* to what's expected.

Comment: So it seems that the interpretation is: find the **start position** of the last occurrence of the search string that **ends at or before startIndex**.

Comment: The OP states: "I would expect it to start looking there and proceed towards the start of the string". That "towards the start of the string" seems to suggest that the direction really isn't the problem.

Comment: @KlausGütter: Yes - and that's really *not* clear in the docs IMO. (The "ends at or before" part.)

Comment: @fubo If you look at my last comment to the question above, maybe you could include that information in your answer if you think it clarifies things!

Comment: *Different starting point as your expectation* - I'm  fairly sure I appreciate the starting point; see the ascii art diagram? You can actually even start the search from index 10 on a 9-long string, yet starting at 11 complains "index must be within the string".. I reasoned this out as the indexes being conceptually between the characters, but "within" is an interpretation exercise

Comment: I'm amused (bemused?:)) by the source code comment that supplying 4 means don't consider any chars after those at index 4.. yet you're allowed to supply startindex 4 for a 4-long string that doesn't hence *have* a char at index 4

Comment: @CaiusJard yea that source code comment from matthew is not obvious but I've tested each index value and it makes sense -`LastIndexOf` turned out to be a rabbit hole and a design bug imo